# Pandas Groupby: Summarizing Activity Log

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to parse an activity log that I have simplified below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Job_Id':[1,1,1,2,2,2],
                   'Activity': ['issued', 'assigned', 'complete', 'issued',    'assigned', 'complete'],
                   'Timestamp': ['2015-07-23 19:02:36', '2015-07-23 19:57:47', '2015-07-23 20:35:22','2015-07-23 18:10:11','2015-07-23 19:00:47', '2015-07-23 19:01:36']})
```

Looks like this...

```
    Activity  Job_Id            Timestamp
0    issued       1  2015-07-23 19:02:36
1  assigned       1  2015-07-23 19:57:47
2  complete       1  2015-07-23 20:35:22
3    issued       2  2015-07-23 18:10:11
4  assigned       2  2015-07-23 19:00:47
5  complete       2  2015-07-23 19:01:36
```

I would like to summarize each job into a single row like below...

```
Job_Id   Issued                Assigned              Complete
1        2015-07-23 19:02:36   2015-07-23 19:57:47   2015-07-23 20:35:22
2        2015-07-23 18:10:11   2015-07-23 19:00:47   2015-07-23 19:01:36
```

I've used groupby in the past but can't seem to get this to work. I would really appreciate some help or suggestions in how to transform this activity log into  the format that I've highlighted. This groupby statement shows the "issued" timestamp but doesn't give me what I need.

```
grouped = df.groupby(['Job_Id']).agg(lambda x: np.array(x[x['Activity'] == 'issued']['Timestamp'])[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a perfect usecase for `pivot_table`:

```
df.pivot_table(columns=['Activity'],values=['Timestamp'],index=['Job_Id'], aggfunc=lambda x : x)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.